# iOS in what conditions is controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType: called

Tags: ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller

Regarding `NSFetchedResultsController`'s delegate:

It's not clear to me from the documentation in what conditions `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` is called.

If you're using an `NSFetchedResultsController` with only a single section is `controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` ever called at all?

Because I deleted all the objects/rows in my FRC with a single section and...

`controller:didChangeObject:atIndexPath:forChangeType:newIndexPath:` was called

`controller:didChangeSection:atIndex:forChangeType:` was never called.

Answer (score 1):

> Notifies the receiver of the addition or removal of a section.

Deleting the object/rows will not trigger this method. If you had only 1 section then added a new section or had multiple sections and removed one, this method would fire.

Comment: Yes, but sections are added/removed via setting the sort descriptors on the FRC I thought. So by setting even a single sort descriptor shouldn't I get at least 1 call to this method? Or do you need multiple sort descriptors for this to ever fire?